# Lambda expression "=>"

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to understand a code but I can't understand what 'p' var is.

```
public Prediction(Game kkk,bool checkit, params State[] checkStates)
    : base(game, p => Manager.method(kkk, p))
{
    this.checkit = checkit;
    this.checkStates = checkStates;
}
```

The second class:

```
public PiratePrediction(Game game, System.Func<Pirate, T> valueExtractor)
{
    this.game = game;

    this.valueExtractor = valueExtractor;

    this.predictedValues = new Dictionary<Pirate, T>();

    this.totalPredictions = 0;
    this.correctPredictions = 0;
}
```

Comment: It's the parameter that is passed into the anonymous method.

Comment: See [SO Whats the point of a lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873603/whats-the-point-of-a-lambda-expression)

Comment: Nor do we since you did not post the constructor of the base class that is called.

Comment: @Abion47 how can I detect the anonymous method?

Comment: @Sagi Define "detect".

Comment: @Abion47 How can I understand what is the anonymous function? I mean like, in this class there are about 5 different methods.

Comment: P is of type Pirate. Search for usage of valueExtractor in PiratePrediction class

Comment: @kalten yeah, but which pirate is that? ( I mean like which object reference is that)

Comment: See declaration of `Manager.method()` the second argument has the type of `p` which you're looking for.

Comment: @Sagi `p => Manager.method(kkk, p)` is the anonymous method. It's a method which takes `p` as a parameter and calls `Manager.method(kkk, p)`. So when some code actually ends up calling it, *that* is when you have a specific value for `p` to think about.

Comment: @Sagi It's not any specific "pirate". It's an anonymous method that you call, and when you call it, you pass a `Pirate` object as a parameter. Also, do you know what an anonymous method is?

Comment: @Mobigital Yeah, I know the kind of p, Im trying to understand which object is it. I mean like -> the specific object

Comment: @Abion47 No, I don't know

Comment: Can you add some code usage of the `valueExtractor` property ?

Comment: @sagi the object is not yet known, because you are dealing with only a `Lambda` body here, this `base` constructor expects to receive the `runnable function` which lambda represents. and then it will call it at some other time with actual `p` value. you can look at the code of the base constructor and see when it calls the handle it receives on 2nd argument. the 2nd argument to that function will be your `p`. don't forget to upvote.

Comment: @Sagi I'm assigning you some required reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: @katlen
 private System.Func<Pirate, T> valueExtractor; -> type

Comment: @Mobigital he should receive a parameter with the name 'p'? -> then it will call it?

Comment: @Sagi, look for usages of `valueExtractor` in `PiratePrediction` class. There should be call like `somevar  =  valueExtractor(..., vvv)`  where `vvv` is your `p` you're looking for. Maybe post the entire `PiratePrediction` class in the edit. Although this lambda could be used pretty much anywhere in your program. So origin of actual `p` parameter could be in another class as well, as long as it has access to `valueExtractor` lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the class you're using on https://github.com/YoavKa/Skillz2016/blob/f23d25eed4baa9786cf517583ee867075a2f0505/API/Prediction/PiratePrediction.cs

the `valueExtractor` lambda is used from `Update`, and `p` comes from the keys of `predictedValues` dictionary.

```
 public virtual void Update()
 {
       foreach (var pair in this.predictedValues)
       {
          if (pair.Key.State != PirateState.Lost && !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(pair.Value, default(T)))
           {
                this.totalPredictions++;
                if (this.valueExtractor(pair.Key).Equals(pair.Value))
                    this.correctPredictions++;
            }
        }
        this.predictedValues.Clear();
    }
```

the `p` comes from the call to `Predict` method of PiratePrediction class. Because it's added to the `predictedValues` array.

```
    public T Predict(Pirate p)
    {
        if (this.predictedValues.ContainsKey(p))
            return this.predictedValues[p];
        T predictedValue = this.predict(p);
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(predictedValue, default(T)))
            return default(T);
        this.predictedValues.Add(p, predictedValue);
        return predictedValue;
    }
```

Comment: I love you. 
Thanks you mate!

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a parameter being passed into your method. A `Func<T, TOut>` is a `delegate`, meaning a method signature.

Consider the following:

```
private class DisplayClass
{ 
    public readonly Game kkk;
    public DisplayyClass(Game kkk) { this.kkk = kkk; }
    public T handler(Pirate p) { return Manager.method(kkk, p); }
}

public Prediction(Game kkk,bool checkit, params State[] checkStates)
    : base(game, new DisplayClass(kkk).handler)
{
    this.checkit= checkit;
    this.checkStates = checkStates;
}
```

This is what the compiler does to your code when interpreting lambdas - it may be a good idea to pass your code through a decompiler to see the exact phrasing.

The `p` variable, as you can see in the expanded code, is a parameter into the method, and lambdas are just a shorthand way to pass methods which can then be invoked in other code.

```
// Somewhere in the base class...
void ExtractValue(Pirate p)
{ 
    // ...
    T value = this.valueExtractor(p);
    // ...
}
```

When thus invoked, `p` will be the value passed in by that other code, and by definition of [`Func<Pirate, T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx), will be of type `Pirate`.

Keep in mind that the code you're passing a lambda to can invoke the code inside your lambda multiple times, such as is the case with [`.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx). I suggest not only reading up on lambdas, but also their extensive use in the [`Linq` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A lambda expression is a declaration of an anonymous method. So imagine that this:

```
p => Manager.method(kkk, p)
```

is equal to this:

```
private T SomeMethod<T>(Pirate p)
{
    return Manager.method(kkk, p);
}
```

You wouldn't be able to do the second snippet in your situation, however, because `kkk` is a local variable from the scope of where the lambda expression was declared, which means that while the lambda can use `kkk`, an explicit method declaration can't (See [Closure](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained)). This is just one benefit of lambdas over declared methods.